# HTTP Method Security

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-mongo, spring-hateoas

I'm working on building a simple HATEOAS REST service with Spring Boot.

I have a MongoDB repository and resource where I would like to allow GET, but disallow all else. (POST, UPDATE DELETE, etc.)

The general idea is to allow a "USER" to do as it wishes with the resoure and allow "PUBLIC" read-only access.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String>
{
    @Secured("ROLE_USER")
    public void delete(Person person);

    @Secured("ROLE_USER")
    public Person save(Person person);

    @Secured("ROLE_USER, ROLE_PUBLIC")
    public Person findOne(String id);
}
```

I don't feel I'm approaching this at the right angle. What's the preferred way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using spring-data-rest and skipping controllers entirely.

First thing you're having a problem with is that @Secured takes an array of roles...so i think your check on findOne is looking for a role **ROLE_USER, ROLE_PUBLIC** not either of those roles.  Changing it to:

```
@Secured({"ROLE_USER", "ROLE_PUBLIC"})
```

might solve your problems.

After that you have a few options to consider

Option 1: Switch to ROLE_ANONYMOUS instead of ROLE_PUBLIC which is the default role anonymous users are assigned in Spring Web w/ spring security.

Option 2: Make sure anonymous users have the ROLE_PUBLIC (which they won't by default, they have ROLE_ANONYMOUS by default).  There's a lot of ways to do this, see http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/anonymous.html

Option 3: Switch to @PreAuthorize annotations for securing methods and use the EL expression like:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER') or isAnonymous()")
```

see http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html note you have to enable pre-post annotation processing.

Final note, ROLE_USER is not a default role...it's DEFAULT_USER for most stuff.

this is a very open ended question and there's a lot of solutions, you'd have to give more context as to your desires to narrow it down.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Chris. The information does help.